# Read actual file size while file is getting copied

Tags: macos, file, filesize

Is there a way to know the actual file size when the file is being copied? When I do an ls -l, it gives the size that is already copied, not the actual size.

Comment: Is this part of a program you are writing? Otherwise, it's likely to be more on-topic on [unix.se] or [apple.se].

Comment: you'd have to create the file sparse first, then fill it in without truncating; otherwise you should expect exactly what you see... the actual current destination file size, not the original file size.

Comment: @Arc676.. it is part of the program that I am writing